# MySQL Stored Procedure Syntax Issues (Eclipse SQL Explorer)

Tags: mysql, eclipse, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1064

Evening folks,

I'm having trouble writing a Stored Procedure for MySql, I've read through a few tutorials as I'm more used to writing Stored Procs for Sybase.

There's something not right with this procedure around line 8.  I've tried changing loads of stuff about it and simplifying it down, but I still can't get it to work.

I'm running this code through Eclipse SQL Explorer plugin.

Starting to wonder if its some settings on the server end.

Can anyone see a reason why this wouldn't work?

```
     DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS myDB.myProc;
     GO
     CREATE PROCEDURE myProc(
        IN p1 INT,
        IN p2 INT,
        IN p3 INT,
        IN p4 INT,
        IN p5 TEXT)
     BEGIN
        DECLARE dateToday DATETIME;
        SELECT dateToday = GETDATE();

        INSERT INTO myTable(id_p1, 
                            id_p2, 
                            id_p3, 
                            id_p4,
                            id_p5,
                            id_p6)
                    VALUES(p1,
                            p2,
                            p3,
                            p4,
                            p5,
                            dateToday);    
     END
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Cheers,

Dave McB

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about MySQL sintax, but the variable shouldn't be like this? :

```
DECLARE @dateToday DATETIME;
Set @dateToday = NOW();
```

Also, I think `Getdate()` is for `MSSQL`, you should use `NOW()` in `MySQL`

Comment: Using the @ flag throws the syntax error near '@dateToday DATETIME' instead of its usual near '', i'm used to the @ method as well, much easier to read, MySQL doesn't seem to like it though... :(

Cheers for the NOW() tip though! GETDATE() was just a stab in the dark from experience lol :)